# Exception happening for test class using springRunner.class while running "mvn clean install"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build

I have tried to build my application via cmd using command "mvn clean install". The build is success. But getting as error in between as shown.

```
2021-Jun-18 10:55:21 AM [main] INFO  com.reserveinventory.api.ReserveInventoryApiControllerIntegrationTest - Started ReserveInventoryApiControllerIntegrationTest in 6.565 seconds (JVM running for 11.97)

2021-Jun-18 10:55:22 AM [scheduling-1] ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path cannot be null
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:74) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:249) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.AssertParameter.notNull(AssertParameter.groovy:26) ~[rest-assured-all-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.AssertParameter$notNull.callStatic(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:196) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:216) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1598) ~[rest-assured-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1661) ~[rest-assured-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184) ~[groovy-2.5.8.jar:2.5.8]
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:175) ~[rest-assured-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.reserveinventory.tokengeneration.TokenGeneration.gettoken(TokenGeneration.java:33) ~[classes/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.398 s - in com.reserveinventory.api.ReserveInventoryApiControllerIntegrationTest
2021-Jun-18 10:55:22 AM [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-Jun-18 10:55:22 AM [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.3:war (default-war) @ reserveinventory ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [reserveinventory] in [D:\ReserveInventory\ReserveInventorySRC\target\InventorySegmentation]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\ReserveInventory\ReserveInventorySRC\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1144 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\ReserveInventory\ReserveInventorySRC\target\InventorySegmentation.war
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.1.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ reserveinventory ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ reserveinventory ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ reserveinventory ---
[INFO] Installing D:\ReserveInventory\ReserveInventorySRC\target\InventorySegmentation.war to C:\Users\shilpa.nair01\.m2\repository\com\reserveinventory\reserveinventory\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\reserveinventory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing D:\ReserveInventory\ReserveInventorySRC\pom.xml to C:\Users\shilpa.nair01\.m2\repository\com\reserveinventory\reserveinventory\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\reserveinventory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.804 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-18T10:55:28+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/124M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my class having sceduler

```
@Service
public class TokenGeneration {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("YY-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"); 
      private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TokenGeneration.class);
      @Autowired
      private Environment env;
      
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay =  120 * 1000)
    public void gettoken() {
        
        System.out.println("Date and Time-->"+dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        String username= env.getProperty(ConstantValues.USERNAME);
        String password= env.getProperty(ConstantValues.PASSWORD);
        String authUrl= env.getProperty(ConstantValues.TOKEN_URL);
        Response response = given().auth()
                .preemptive().basic(username, password)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .post(authUrl);
            logger.info("Response body"+ response.getBody().asString());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody().asString());
            String token = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
```

I have used scheduler in my application and it is working fine. can anyone help me out why this error is happening.

UPDATE: This exception is due to the test class.My test class using springRunner.class . When I changed to MockitoJUnitRunner.class exception was gone. Whats the issue with springrunner.class
PFB the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ReserveInventoryApiControllerIntegrationTest {
     @Test
        public void segmentInventoryTest()  {
     }
     }
```

Comment: that error is because the userName is null. Have you read the error message? this is a runtime error, so it's very possible you can build your application without encountering it

Comment: I am not sure which username. My scheduled job has as username field to fetch token . That value is coming from application.properties file

Comment: So can i igore this? The application is running fine.

Comment: your application throws an Exception. That's not exactly the same as "running fine"

Comment: This is happening while mvn clean install and also the build is success.I have also added the sceduler class. Could you please help to find the issue. Also the error shows "userName" But in my code there is no field like that. Is that coming internally?

Comment: might be. but at this point, it's the path that is null. Check what exactly it is of the build process that throws this exception.

Comment: I have updated the question .Could you please check that

Comment: It's not a good runner to run SpringBoot tests with

Comment: So shall I change to Mockito? when I updated like this the error gone.@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@MockBean(TokenGeneration.class)
@SpringBootTest